# While loop and if-else statement proper indentation

Tags: python, if-statement

I am pretty new to python and am learning while loops and if else statements. Previously I've only seen if-else statements by themselves underneath a def statement or when included with a while loop, underneath the while loop properly indented. My question; when using a while loop, is it possible to place the if-else statement at the same level of indentation as the while loop and if so how would that be read?

Was expecting the if-else statements to be indented underneath the while loop.

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w81H0.jpg)

Comment: Pleases don't post images of text. Include the code in your question formatted as code (highlight the code and select the "{}"button).

Comment: _when using a while loop, is it possible to place the if-else statement at the same level of indentation as the while loop_ Sure, if the intent is to execute the if-else statement AFTER the while loop has finished.

Comment: Also, it's a bit odd that you say "is it possible to place the if-else statement ...", as if having an if-else is a REQUIREMENT of a while loop.  It isn't.  Some while loops have an if-else statement inside the loop and also one afterward, some loops have one or the other, and some loops don't have either.  There is no explicit connection.

Answer (score 1):

yeah it makes sense to have if statements outside while loops at the same level -  depending on the context, check this example out.

```
x=1
while x<5:
    print(str(x) + " still less than 5")
    x=x+1
if x==3:
    print(str(x) + " x is currently 3")
else:
    print(str(x) + " x is not 3")
```

result:

```
1 still less than 5
2 still less than 5
3 still less than 5
4 still less than 5
5 x is not 3
```

why didn't the program print x is currently at 3? because the while loop will complete execution until no longer true (x is not less than 5, so x has arrived at 5), then exits, then runs the code below. x is not 3, so it hits the else statement at the end.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of a `while loop`, the code within the loop is indented underneath the `while statement` to indicate that it belongs to the loop body. Similarly, an `if-else` statement is typically indented underneath the `if` or `else` keyword to define the `conditional` blocks where we can for example break the while loop.

However, it isn't possible to place an `if-else` statement at the same level of indentation as the while loop.

The Correct structure should be something like this

```
while condition:
    # Loop body
    # ...

    if condition1:
        # Code block for condition1
        # ...

    else:
        # Code block for other conditions
        # ...

    # Code outside the if-else block, but still within the while loop

# Code outside the while loop
```

In this structure, the `if-else` statement is evaluated within each iteration of the `while loop`. If `condition1` is `true`, the code block under `if condition1:` is executed. Otherwise, the code block under `else:` is executed. Once the execution of the `if-else` block is complete, the loop continues to the next iteration, re-evaluates the loop condition, and repeats the process until the condition becomes `False`.

---

You can still have an `if-else` block at the same indentation level of the while loop but it has nothing to do with the `while` loop and essentially you'd need to break out of the `while` loop for the blocks beneath to be executed

```
counter = 0
while counter != 3:
    print("Hello World")
    counter+=1

another_counter = 0
if another_counter > 0:
    print("bigger than 0")
else:
    print("smaller than 0")
```

*Output*

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
smaller than 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call your example "at the same level of indentation" as the while loop.  That would be the part you label "Code outside the while loop".

Comment: Thanks also for your answer, I just updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @logisticaggresor Seeing your updated answer, it all depends on the use case you want, while maintaining Python's correct syntax.